# how to have value of a variable in onCreat() to be used in a different method

Tags: java, android

i have value of a variable 'position' in my oncreate which i got it from a different activity using getIntent(). now i want to use the value of this position in a different method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tatslideshow);
            Intent j = getIntent();
    int position = j.getExtras().getInt("pos");
}
```

and i want to use position in this method

```
public void updateUI() {
                   int imgid[] = alltats[position];

.
.
. 
}
```

now i know i can pass the value by putting parameters in updateUI() like updateUI(position) and use it. but the problem is i also have a subclass in my class where i am calling this method so i cant put parameters in updateUI().  this is the subclass:

```
class RefreshHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TatSlideShow.this.updateUI();
    }
    }
```

TatSlideShow is the main class. please tell me the way to achieve it.

Comment: declare it as class level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `getIntent().getExtras().getInt("pos")` from `updateUI()` directly, since  `updateUI()` is a non static method of your Activity.

Comment: can getintent be used outside oncreate()? I tried once outside of methods but is crashes my application

Comment: I tried it works.. The reason for crashing must be NPE, and  your Intent.extra must be null..

Comment: yup it works. so getintent can be called in non static methods.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you will have to use a parameter along with method as you already know...Because the scope of variables within methods are within the method block itself.
Otherwise they will be destroyed once they are out of it.

Otherwise you will have to use the variable position directly within the UpdateUI method like.

```
public void updateUI() 
{
               position=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("pos");
               int imgid[] = alltats[position];
}
```